# "Invalid column name 'CustomerName'"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a software that will receive information from a user in a gooey and then apply the information to my SQL database after the 'Save' button is pressed. I am receiving an error that states "Invalid Column name 'CustomerName'", even though my spelling is correct and consistent throughout the file and is the exact same as what is in my database. I have included brackets to try and make sure that the CustomerName is being read in SQL and still receive the same error. I have also parametrized the query and still no luck. The exception in my try tells me it is within this block but I have stared at it for too long to be able to see anything wrong. Any suggestions??

```
 Else
        If log = vbNullString Then
            log = "No Input"
        End If
        Try
            Dim con2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectString)
            con2.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
            Dim sql1 As String = "Insert Into WorkOrders (DateIn, DateTime, Problem, WhoTook, Tech, DateOut, [WONum], [BuildingRoom], [Open], [CustomerName], [CustomerPhone], [CustomerEmail], TaskType, PCProb, ProjectorProb, VisualizerProb, MicProb, SecondaryInputProb, ControlSysProb, RemoteProb, ConnectivityProb, CableProb, OtherProb, ActTaskType, ActPCProb, ActProjectorProb, ActVisualizerProb, ActMicProb, ActSecondaryInputProb, ActControlSysProb, ActRemoteProb, ActConnectivityProb, ActCableProb, ActOtherProb, EndNotes, FeedbackGrade, FeedbackComments, CompleteClosedByID, TicketLog) Values (@DateIn, @DateTime, @Problem, @WhoTook, @Tech, @DateOut, @WONum, @BuildingRoom, @Open, @CustomerName, @CustomerPhone, @CustomerEmail, @TaskType, @PCProb, @ProjectorProb, @VisualizerProb, @MicProb, @SecondaryInputProb, @ControlSysProb, @RemoteProb, @ConnectivityProb, @CableProb, @OtherProb, @ActTaskType, @ActPCProb, @ActProjectorProb, @ActVisualizerProb, @ActMicProb, @ActSecondaryInputProb, @ActControlSysProb, @ActRemoteProb, @ActConnectivityProb, @ActCableProb, @ActOtherProb, @EndNotes, @FeedbackGrade, @FeedbackComments, @CompleteClosedByID, @TicketLog)"
            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql1, con2)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateIn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateIn
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TimeScheduled
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Problem", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ProbTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WhoTook", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = EmployeeBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tech", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOut", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = TimeScheduled
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WONum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = WorkOrderNum
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BuildingRoom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = BuildingRoomTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Open", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = WOOpenButton.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CustomerNameComboBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerPhone", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CustomerPhoneTextBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CustomerEmailTextBox.Text
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TaskType)) Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskType", DBNull.Value)
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TaskType
            End If
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PCProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = PCBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectorProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ProjectorBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@VisualizerProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = VisualizerBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MicProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = MicBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecondaryInputProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = SecondaryBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ControlSysProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ControlBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RemoteProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = RemotesBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ConnectivityProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ConnectivityBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CableProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CableBox.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OtherProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = OtherBox.Checked
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TaskType)) Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActTaskType", DBNull.Value)
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActTaskType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ActTaskType
            End If
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActPCProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActPC.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActProjectorProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActProjector.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActVisualizerProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActVisualizer.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActMicProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActMic.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActSecondaryInputProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActSecondary.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActControlSysProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActControl.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActRemoteProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActRemote.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActConnectivityProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActConnectivity.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActCableProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActCable.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActOtherProb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActOther.Checked
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndNotes", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SolutionBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FeedbackGrade", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SolutionBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FeedbackComments", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SolutionBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompleteClosedByID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeBox.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TicketLog", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = log
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con2.Close()
            If EmployeeBox.Text = vbNullString Then
                EmployeeBox.Text = vbNullString
            Else : WOs.AssignTech(EmployeeBox.Text)
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("New Record added")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the source of your problem, but a column named DateTime seems to be problematic regarding reserved keywords.I would put square brackets around it also

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue but is definitely a good catch that i did not take into account. Thanks Steve

Comment: Another idea, are you sure about the connectionstring used? Sometime you think to work with a database instead you are using a different one. This happens a lot when the connectionstring contains the substitution string |DataDirectory| with AttachDbFileName.

Comment: Verify that your WorkOrders table has a CustomerName column, and it's not some slight variation of that spelling.

Comment: Is your combobox databound?

Comment: I figured it out. It had to do with my connectionstring for that specific project page. Thanks for all the help and suggestions, I feel silly knowing it was as minor and as that but glad I could get the show on the road! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, are you sure about the connectionstring used? Sometime you think to work with a database instead you are using a different one. This happens a lot when the connectionstring contains the substitution string |DataDirectory| with AttachDbFileName. –  Steve

My connectionstring was pointing to the wrong directory. Thanks for all the help!